# h:inputFile value becomes blank after submit or validation fail of other input, how to retain its value?

Tags: forms, validation, file-upload, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

With many other standard JSF components, when a form is submitted and server side validation fails, the page is rendered again with the previously submitted form fields filled in for the user to edit and resubmit.  I am looking for that same behavior from the new h:inputFile and I'm not finding it.

As a simple example, I have a form with an h:inputText and an h:inputFile.  The inputText has server side validation enabled.  If the user enters invalid text and selects a file and submits, the file is uploaded and the form is rendered with the invalid text in the text field and a h:message indicating the validation result.  The issue I'm trying to address is at this point they correct their text input, but have to select a file again, and upload it again.  Is there something basic I am missing, or is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML disallows prefilling an `<input type="file">` as that otherwise opens a [huge security hole](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1696884). As JSF is in this context just a HTML code generator, it can't do much against that.

Your best bet is to ajax-submit the form and ajax-render **only** the parts which really need to be updated, such as messages (i.e. don't use `render="@form"`). This way the initial input value stays.

E.g.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:inputText id="text" />
    <h:message id="m_text" for="text" />

    <h:inputFile id="file" />
    <h:message id="m_file" for="file" />

    <h:commandButton value="submit">
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="m_text m_file" />
    </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

#### See also:

- [Understanding PrimeFaces process/update and JSF f:ajax execute/render attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes)